# TypeScript type definition for inconsistently typed object

Tags: typescript

I have a large JSON-like object that has a lot of nesting, but ultimately becomes a and I'd like to be able to create a type-safe function for pulling any arbitrary string or object out of the nested structure.

For example, here's a structure like what I have:

```
const obj = {
  "keyA": {
    "nestedA1": "string",
    "nestedA2": "string"
  },
  "keyB": {
    "nestedB1" : {
      "doubleNested1": "string",
      "doubleNested2": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote the following function, which works at the final nesting level to get a type-safe string out of the object:

```
const getConfig = <T extends string>(collection: Record<T, string>, key: T): string => {
  return collection[key];
}
```

This works for the following use-cases, the way I want it to.

```
getConfig(obj.keyA, "nestedA1") // compiles
getConfig(obj.keyB.nestedB1, "doubleNested") // compiles
getConfig(obj.keyA, "somethingRandom") // compile error
```

However, I'd really like to be able to select not just a string but a strongly typed object from the structure as well. I'd like to be able to do the following, for example:

```
getConfig(obj.keyB, "nestedB1").doubleNested1
getConfig(obj, "keyA").nestedA1
```

I want to modify the type signature of the function to indicate it can return a string OR an object, AND of the correct type so that I can continue to drill deeper into the object that is returned. How can I do this? Especially when the type is not a `Record<T,R>` for example because not every `R` value in the object has the same type (ie, `keyA` and `keyB` do not have the same type signature)

Thank you!

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGBrApgJ4CCAXBtjjGPtPgCbECM5A5NAE4CWYA5qwBpKOGnUYAmNpx78hOAL5y8RAELksVarSgMVLCppz0QAV3gAbfADltDfeyjc+g4VWNnLNsZJgOns10VKIPkAbkxMUEhYXnwoAGFwADMuXlQYAB4AFQEYAGkYfAAPHTB6CGVCECSYLIA+AApQc0tgKC5wchzK8jyASi6AbTyAXVQ6gxgOOJMOMBhm1vbwQYJCEfCwiNiE5NSGhEQAOjWVXNZRHXo9Vj6j9wtrW3omcJ3EsBTeA6RzteJbkdLgxmKEgA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame This is close to what I'm looking for! The thing it's missing is that my initial solution allowed me to pass a `string` type and the function essentially type-checked it as a valid key. The proposed solution doesn't seem to work when something is explicitly a string type instead of a raw string defined inline. Link too long for this comment, see next comment for playground link

Comment: @wonderflame [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGBrApgJ4CCAXBtjjGPtPgCbECM5A5NAE4CWYA5qwBpKOGnUYAmNpx78hOAL5y8RAELksVarSgMVLCppz0QAV3gAbfADltDfeyjc+g4VWNnLNsZJgOns10VKIPkAbkwI0EhYXnwoAGFwADMuXiZUGAAeABUYfAAPHTB6CBhpPgA+AApQc0tgKC5wcgAlfFAOehyBMscZCp6CQnJsgEpyct5UCoMYDjiTDjAYWvrG8ABtIYBdcPlI8GgYWITk1PEM7pgAaTzC-GLSoZAkmGzq1fb1sBHBonJruM3htrttprN5lBFstPg0mmAtkRdpgwgdoloxMwJn0+BlWKIdIwmKxMCdEmAUmkqghEAA6IbEHoEhjMUZoo7M+h6bH+PGcvQkslnXjialIemqJm2LlMUa09wWazSpjhIUU85ixA9VgM1hyznMUJAA)

Comment: If you will pass a string then it won't infer the return type correctly. So there is no point of passing a `string` to the function